# Google Glass Timeline notifications for In built actions and custom actions are not working after updation(of XE-16 glass update)

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

We have developed a google glass ware(timeline based) app. In that first we will send some timeline cards to the glass with some inbuilt menu items and custom menu items.

and we have configured the proxy url for getting notifications for time line.

It worked fine for so many days.

**But After Google Glass XE-16 update we are not getting the timeline notifications**

Can you please guide us inresolving the issue.

Hi Prisoner,

**for inserting timeline we have used the following code:**

```
global $base_url="http:\/\/mysite.com\/mirror"; 

$client = get_google_api_client(); 

$client->setAccessToken(get_credentials($_SESSION['userid'])); // A glass service for interacting with the Mirror API 

$mirror_service = new Google_MirrorService($client); 

    $new_timeline_item = new Google_TimelineItem();
    $new_timeline_item->setText('Hey I am testing new');

    $notification = new Google_NotificationConfig();
    $notification->setLevel("DEFAULT");
    $new_timeline_item->setNotification($notification);

    $menu_items = array();
    $custom_menu_item = new Google_MenuItem();
    $custom_menu_value = new Google_MenuValue();
    $custom_menu_value->setDisplayName("Add Item");
    $custom_menu_value->setIconUrl( $base_url . "/static/images/tulip.jpg");
    $custom_menu_item->setValues(array($custom_menu_value));
    $custom_menu_item->setAction("CUSTOM");
    $custom_menu_item->setId("add_to_cart_item"); // This is how you identify it on the notification ping
    array_push($menu_items, $custom_menu_item);
    $new_timeline_item->setMenuItems($menu_items);


    insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $new_timeline_item, "image/jpeg", file_get_contents($base_url . "/static/images/tulip.jpg"));
```

for this we are trying to add new custom menus and built in menus like (pin,delete,share,send)

**To subscribe to notifications we have used the Google glass Php mirror api function.**

```
subscribe_to_notifications($mirror_service, "timeline", $_SESSION['userid'], $base_url . "/notify.php");
```

All these are working fine before XE-16 version update. After updation we are not able to get notification for time line card notifications

Comment: Can you elaborate, and possibly show some code, to illustrate how you are inserting the cards and registering for notifications.

Comment: Hi Prisoner,

for inserting timeline we have used the following code:
global $base_url;
$client = get_google_api_client();
$client->setAccessToken(get_credentials($_SESSION['userid']));
// A glass service for interacting with the Mirror API
$mirror_service = new Google_MirrorService($client);
$timeline_item = new Google_TimelineItem();
$timeline_item->setText("Welcome to the Mirror API PHP Quick Start");
insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $timeline_item, null, null);

for this we are trying to add new custom menus and built in menus like (pin,delete,share,send).

Comment: Please edit the original question

Comment: Hi Prisoner,

To subscribe to notifications we have used the Google glass Php mirror api funtion.

subscribe_to_notifications($mirror_service, "timeline",
    $_SESSION['userid'], $base_url . "/notify.php");

All these are working fine before XE-16 version update. 

After updation we are not able to get notification for time line card notifications

Comment: Hi Prisoner, I have updated the Question with code. Please check it once and let us know about this.

Comment: the example you've given doesn't show adding menu items at all, so it is difficult to see why it may not be working. You also need to make sure that $base_url is set correctly and that the /notify.php at that address responds.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, Thanks for the response, and I have updated the code in question with adding menu items. And the timeline items are inserted with the menu items.And we have used the Proxy url for getting notifications.previously it works fine and we are able to get the notification after click on the custom menu item. After XE-16 update we are not able to get the notification. Can you please look into this one and let us know what is the error. Give suggestions what things we need to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with sending image attachments. See details here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=491

So the part of your code that has to change is:

```
insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $new_timeline_item, "image/jpeg", file_get_contents($base_url . "/static/images/tulip.jpg"));
```

Needs to change to:

```
insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $new_timeline_item, null, null);
```

And use setHTML instead of setText and include an img element with a src tag that points to a web URL. E.g.:

```
<img src="http://example.com/static/images/tulip.jpg" />
```

Note that you also have to factory reset your Glass. You can tell if you have the problem by trying to run a menu command and the spinning double arrow in the bottom right corner gets stuck and an a crash stack trace is visible on ADB logcat output on the Glass. So to fix the problem, first you have to not use image attachments, and second you have to reset the Glass to fix the broken timeline sync on the Glass.